# Why does my character skin keep reverting to a naked girl?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Why does my character's skin keep reverting to a naked girl? I thought someone figured out my password, so i changed it, but after a week or so it got changed back.

I have used mod tools to add aether mod only as well as adding the high def painterly texture pack.

Is there anyway to stop it reverting?

The most recent time happened within the last week.

I've fixed it before without changing my password and it just gets reset to the naked girl skin after i've set it to the default.  Though the newest skin is still of the girl, but at least she's clothed now.

I don't think it is a key logger cause I have a new install of windows in the past month and i've had this problem for more than 6 months.

The problem is that I'm always in first person mode so i hardly even notice.

Also I play on a server and no-one has bothered to mention to me that I look like a girl, so I wonder if it is client side.

Comment: I *sooooo* want to answer that one with "Because Minecraft is secretly reading your mind and trying its best to figure out what you'd wish to see at this moment." ...

Comment: Questions on this site should be about problems. :P

Comment: When did it start?  And if they have a keylogger on your computer or something then changing your password isn't going to help.

Comment: happened to me i am dure its because of the minecraft database but i fixed it by waiting a few days and spamming the change skin button

Comment: Also there's a good possibility that you've installed rogue client mods.

Comment: Screenshots, or it didn't happen... :/

Comment: `no-one has bothered to mention to me that I look like a girl`. did _you_ bother to ask anyone? (Also, do you use a texture pack?)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler heh... no i didn:t but i play with a bunch of close friends, which one woudl hope if i was runnign around in a naked girl avatar they would ask why and not just think i'm some weirdo.  I used a texture pack before but not anymore.  I had used one of the more famous painterly packs.

Comment: @ProSay you might be right it seems to happen around the same time as DB maintenance.

Comment: might be a mod or something if you have any installed, you also try and re download minecraft (if you play from the .exe)

Also check the website that's were your skin would be, try and upload the correct skin again

Comment: @Latency that's what i ended up doing and it got overridden again. So what i did is stop using all mods and texture packs and it seems to be ok for now

Comment: Judging by the "I stopped using 'mods' and it's fine now" and the one answer saying that hacked clients sometimes do this for lolz, this is pretty clearly an instance of piracy. So, voting to close as off topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am a paying user of minecraft, having purchased it back in alpha.

Comment: @MarkHosang It's possible that it's an accidental instance of piracy. Hacked clients are all illegal, even if they need a paid account, because they redistribute Mojang's code instead of just modifications to it that have to be installed by the user. If that sounds like what you were using, well, now you know why those are a bad idea. :) If that doesn't sound familiar, then... who knows what was going on.

Comment: It's like that mirror in harry potter. The Mirror of Erised: The Mirror of Erised is an ancient, ornate mirror. It has clawed feet and a gold frame inscribed with the phrase " Erised stra ehru oyt ube cafru oyt on wohsi." The mirror shows the most desperate desire of a person's heart, a vision that has been known to drive men mad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems by disabling all mods and removing the painterly texture pack fixed my character's skin from being reset to a naked female.

Answer (score 10):

Well, if you're a premium user I wouldn't know why, but the Anjo Caido (pirate'd) Launcher (the force update one) gives you a naked girl skin for fun. Also some hacked/cheat clients do it too.

Comment: if that's the reason, Mark probably won't stand up to accept this answer...

Comment: I've used that launcher.  This is not true.

Comment: I have the retail game. and don't use hacked or cheat clients.

Comment: @JohntheGreen Agreed, it uses the default skin.